# UITableViewCell showing two different items while I move it in edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a basic "To-Do List" iPhone app backed by Core Data.  I am having problems implementing a system that allows the user to select sort order (Alpha, Date Created, Custom).  If they select custom, then they can move items manually via edit mode.

Right now, the table display and core data reflect the sort selection correctly.  However, if I do something like the following I get a weird situation as shown in the screenshot below.

Causes Issue:

1. Start App and change sorting - say from Date Changed to Alpha
2. Change to Custom Sort
3. Try moving an item in edit mode (error only appear while I am holding and dragging an item)

Screenshot:

[image: Image of problem]

When the sort preference is changed, I am essentially killing my NSManagedResultsFetcher, creating a new one with the new sort descriptor and reloading the table

```
- (void)startFetcher
{
    BOOL                            success;
    NSError *                       error;
    NSFetchRequest *                fetchRequest;
    NSSortDescriptor *              sortDescriptor;
    OurListsAppDelegate*    delegate;

    delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

    assert([ListMaster sharedListMaster] != nil);
    assert([ListMaster sharedListMaster].managedObjectContext != nil);

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(parentCreatedUdid = %@) AND (parentCreatedDate = %@)", self.parentCreatedUdid, self.parentCreatedDate];

    if (self.parentItem != nil)
    {
        sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.parentItem.sortPreference ascending:YES] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
       sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:delegate.rootSortPreference ascending:YES] autorelease];
    }

    assert(sortDescriptor != nil);

    fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    assert(fetchRequest != nil);

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:[ListMaster sharedListMaster].listEntity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    assert(self.fetcher == nil);
    self.fetcher = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[ListMaster sharedListMaster].managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    assert(self.fetcher != nil);

    self.fetcher.delegate = self;

    success = [self.fetcher performFetch:&error];
    if ( ! success ) {
        [[QLog log] logWithFormat:@"viewer fetch failed %@", error];
    }
}
```

And the method called when the sort order has been changed

```
- (void)restartFetcher
{
    [_fetcher release];
    self.fetcher = nil;
    [self startFetcher];
    [self reloadTable];
}
```

Edit:  Added code below per request

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *   result;

    assert(tv == self.tableView);
    assert(indexPath != NULL);

    if ( [self hasNoItems] )
    {

        // There are no items to display; return a cell that simple says "No items".

        result = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (result == nil) {
            result = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
            assert(result != nil);

            result.textLabel.text = @"No items";
            result.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            result.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        }
        result.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    } 
    else
    {
        ListItem *         item;


        item = [self.fetcher objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        assert([item isKindOfClass:[ListItem class]]);

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
            assert(cell != nil);

            assert(cell.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue);;
        }

        ToggleImageControl *toggleControl = [[ToggleImageControl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(4, 6, 32, 32) status:item.isDone];
        toggleControl.tag = indexPath.row;  
        [cell.contentView addSubview: toggleControl];

        [toggleControl release];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 260, 44)];

        label.text = item.name;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];        


        if ([item.isList boolValue] == YES)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        result = cell;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Posted the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath as asked.  Thank you for taking a look at this.  I am new to iPhone development, so if anyone has pointers on things to take a look at (but not a defacto solution) it would help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines,

```
ToggleImageControl *toggleControl = [[ToggleImageControl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(4, 6, 32, 32) status:item.isDone];
toggleControl.tag = indexPath.row;  
[cell.contentView addSubview: toggleControl];

[toggleControl release];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 260, 44)];

label.text = item.name;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

This is a problem of cell reuse. Reusable cells need to be reset every time before they are configured. In this case, I realized that this was the problem when I noticed the content of one cell merging with the content of another. When such a thing happens, it usually is the problem. What you're doing wrong is that you are adding both the objects that you create above every time the cell is reused. In case of toggle control, they overlap and you won't notice but text varies and the overlap stands out.

**What you can do?**

You can either search for both the objects and remove them from your cell and then do what you are doing above or you can create a custom subclass of a `UITableViewCell` and add two `retain`ed properties – one for the toggle control and one for the label and later do this,

```
ToggleImageControl *toggleControl = [[ToggleImageControl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(4, 6, 32, 32) status:item.isDone];
toggleControl.tag = indexPath.row;  
cell.toggleControl = toggleControl;

[toggleControl release];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 260, 44)];

label.text = item.name;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

cell.label = label;
[label release];
```

Comment: Works great.  I was looking in the complete wrong place, so this was very helpful.